# Email separator similar to gmail

Tags: jquery, email, gmail, separator

How can i achieve an email separator similar to gmail using jquery, the script will separate the email when it detects the " , " or " " then gives the email individual frames, also allows deletion when clicking the " x ", and edit the email by double clicking

[image]

Comment: jQuery tagging scripts can do something similar

Comment: sir please use your comment as an answer for me to approve it.

Comment: Please accept if it helps you, I have added a link to help you further

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look for jQuery tag type scripts they will do exactly what you're after. Just like this one:

http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

Comment: 8mins I'll approve it when the bond expires

Answer (score 3):

You can also check out `Chosen:` http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#multiple-select

Multiple select is what you want in particular, it can turn `<select>` elements into what you want or fetch options via AJAX.